# Trying to compare two S1000D documents and show change inline

Tags: xml, compare, diff

I am struggling with a couple of S1000D documents which I am proof reading for some minor changes. The documents are large so it's not practical to go through line by line and it would take forever, with some content also moving sections. I need to show what has changed to a reviewer. Is there a software tool I could use to easily compare and present the differences between the two documents in one of those documents.

I've tried some free online tools to compare the raw XML but I need something that compares the content as much as the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Compare S1000D is a solid choice for this; it's available via REST and is straightforward to use - two inputs, one combined delta output.

Comment: Thanks Oliver I'll give it a Google.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple comparison tools in XML IDEs such as Oxygen and XmlSpy, but for the ultimate in flexibility, the specialists in this area are DeltaXML.

Comment: Thanks Michael, much appreciated, I'll check those out.